# Reference for Functional derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am having a hard time understanding how to write functional derivatives. For example, If I have a functional $F: L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$ how can I write $F'$ and $F''$? They are operators in wich space? My guess is that $F': L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n) \to L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)^*$ and $F'': L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n) \to L(L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n),L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)^*)$, where $L(L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n), L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n))$ are the linear maps from $L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n) $ to $L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n)^*$.

Another question, If I have, for example $L^{2}([0,1], \mathbb{R}^n) = E\oplus F$. How can I write $F'$ and $F''$ with respect their partial derivatives? Is this possible?

If anyone could give me some good references, or explain to me that.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey! how did it go? were you able to learn what you needed?